# Selecting values from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Doctor.

Doctor table consist of 4 fields. `DoctorID,DoctorName, DoctorAddress, DoctorSpeciality`

I have another table called PatientData. and it has 4 fields in it. `PatientId, PatientName, PatientTelephone, DoctorID`.

I need to write a SQL that would display the following fields;

```
PatientID, PatientName, DoctorName, DoctorSpeciality
```

1.) I think, i will have to use an `INNER JOIN` here, but i am not sure how to write it for this scenario. An `outer join` would also work i guess, but i am new to `Joins`. Can someone please help me here ?

2.) Can i create a `VIEW` for the `SQL` statement that i am creating above ?

Comment: You might want to re-think your design so that you have a many to many relationship between patients and doctors.

Comment: This is good advice from Dan. Consider this, A Doctor can have many patients, a patient can have many doctors, a doctor can have multiple specialties and a patient can have multiple doctors with the same specialty or multiple doctors with multiple specialties.  They should all be in their own database table using a relationship table to join them. When you query for a patient, you look at the relationship table and grab all of his/her doctors, then grab the specialties of that doctor, and so on.

Comment: I got a little extreme with my example to help show the scenario but you could easily store the specialties as an attribute of the doctor if the data is a 1-1, or you only have a couple of static values.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should would using a regular `INNER JOIN` -- this will return all records from the Doctor table with a matching record in the PatientData table:

```
SELECT PD.PatientId, PD.PatientName, D.DoctorName, D.DoctorSpecialty
FROM Doctor D
   INNER JOIN PatientData PD ON D.DoctorId = PD.DoctorId
```

If you want to return all data from one of the other tables, look into using a `OUTER JOIN` (I prefer `LEFT JOINs`).

Here's a nice article on visual representation of joins: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

And yes, you can create a view if you'd like -- depends on your needs.  Something like this should be close:

```
CREATE VIEW DoctorPatients AS
SELECT PD.PatientId, PD.PatientName, D.DoctorName, D.DoctorSpecialty
FROM Doctor D
   INNER JOIN PatientData PD ON D.DoctorId = PD.DoctorId
```

SQL Server Views: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple join

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientName, d.DoctorName, d.DoctorSpeciality
FROM PatientData p JOIN Doctor d on d.DoctorID = p.PatientID
```

Of course you could create a view from this

```
   CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PatientAndDoctor]
   AS
      SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientName, d.DoctorName, d.DoctorSpeciality
      FROM PatientData p JOIN Doctor d on d.DoctorID = p.PatientID
```